# How to insert or cache pages in an object

Tags: jquery, caching, object

If I have some pages like: (home.html, about.html etc), how can I insert those pages in an object for future use? In other words, I want to cache those pages:

```
var obj= {"home":home.html, "about": about.html};
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj= {"home": "home.html", "about": "about.html"};

alert( obj.about );   // about.html
```

Comment: Note that this will not cache the content of these pages, if that's what you are aiming at. It's only storing the `home.html` and `about.html` strings, like it would store `bananas` and `apples` and `foo` and `bar`.